# Assign multiple value into obj using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Check following html and jQuery code. I just simply need to assign `name` and `email` into `obj` variable as a object where name and email will be the property name and its value from the table td>tr text. I already tried like `obj = Object.assign(obj, {'name':name, 'email': email});` but seems its unable to assign name and email value.

Any idea how to fix it? [Here is fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qw6b8sLn/1/)

Html:

```html
<table class="table table-hover" id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Full Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Email</th>
      <th>#Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>john@example.com</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg remove-btn">
          X
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>smith@example.com</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg remove-btn">
          X
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="insert_td_after_it">
      <td>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          id="fullname_td"
          placeholder="Applicant Full Name"
          value=""
        />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          id="email_td"
          placeholder="Applicant Email"
          value=""
        />
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="addAlert">
          +
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Jquery:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  console.log("rendered.");

  var trs = $("#myTable").find("tbody>tr");

  var obj = {};

  $(trs).each(function (index, content) {
    var name = jQuery(content).find("td:eq(0)").text();
    var email = jQuery(content).find("td:eq(1)").text();

    obj = Object.assign(obj, { name: name, email: email });
  }); //each() finish

  console.log(obj);
}); //ready() finish
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question with an example of the result you want? JS objects can't have duplicate properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To assign name and email values as properties of the obj object, you need to create a new object for each row and assign the name and email values as properties of that object. Then you can add each new object to an array using the push() method. Here's the modified jQuery code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("rendered.");

    var trs = $("#myTable").find("tbody>tr");

    var objArr = [];

    $( trs ).each(function( index, content ) {

        var name = jQuery(content).find('td:eq(0)').text();
        var email = jQuery(content).find('td:eq(1)').text();

        var newObj = {};
        newObj['name'] = name;
        newObj['email'] = email;

        objArr.push(newObj);
    });

    console.log(objArr);
});
```

In this code, we first create an empty array objArr to hold the new objects. Then, inside the each() loop, we create a new object newObj and assign the name and email values as properties of that object. Finally, we push the new object to the objArr array. At the end of the loop, objArr will contain an array of objects, each with a name and email property corresponding to the values from each row of the table.

Answer (score 1):

Just change `var obj = {}` to `var obj = []` and:

```js
obj = Object.assign(obj, { name: name, email: email });
```

to:

```js
obj.push(Object.assign({}, { name: name, email: email }));
```

because there in the array of `tbody>tr`, only the last element which success retrieved. So if you want to get all `name` and `email`, create an array of objects instead of a single object.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  console.log("rendered.");

  var trs = $("#myTable").find("tbody>tr");

  var obj = [];

  $(trs).each(function (index, content) {
    var name = jQuery(content).find("td:eq(0)").text();
    var email = jQuery(content).find("td:eq(1)").text();
    obj.push(Object.assign({}, { name: name, email: email }));
  }); //each() finish

  console.log(obj);
}); //ready() finish
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover" id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Full Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Email</th>
      <th>#Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>john@example.com</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg remove-btn">
          X
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>smith@example.com</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg remove-btn">
          X
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="insert_td_after_it">
      <td>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          id="fullname_td"
          placeholder="Applicant Full Name"
          value=""
        />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          id="email_td"
          placeholder="Applicant Email"
          value=""
        />
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="addAlert">
          +
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try with this code-

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  console.log("rendered.");
  var obj = [];
  $("#myTable tbody>tr").each(function (index, content) {
    var data = {};
    var name = jQuery(this).find("td:eq(0)").text();
    var email = jQuery(this).find("td:eq(1)").text();
    data.name = name;
    data.email = email;
    obj.push(data);
}); 
console.log(obj);
});
```